# Plugin for TinyMCE to create reference to other posts

Tags: plugins, posts, permalinks, seo

Is there any plugin that would allow me to easily insert reference to another post for TinyMCE?  I want to be able to reference another post by permalink and the link text to be the title of the post.
Alternatively, is there any plugin that allow me to do this with short-code? i.e

```
[reference post-id="2345" link="peramlink"]
```

Comment: Is the built-in linking with content search not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `W4 Internal Link Shortcode` plugin is what you're looking for:

> Now you can easily embed your wordpress sites internal links (of post,
>   page ,category, author) in post content, page content or category
>   description area. Just write the appropriate shortcode, and you are
>   done. No need to update these links whenever you make any changes to
>   the real link location.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w4-internal-link-shortcode/